# Strange Concurrence on lines.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I got really stuck proving this exercice of my text on geometry. Can anyone provide a solution please?

> If the lines $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$ concur, then the points of intersection of the lines:
>
> $AB,A'B'$; $BC,B'C'$; $CA,C'A'$; $A'B,BA'$; $B'C,BC'$; $C'A,AC'$ lie by thirds on 4 separated lines

Here's a picture of the initial situation:

[image]

I really tried everything on my text and did lots of sketches but failed.

Please, help.

Comment: Are those lines or segments? What do you mean by concur?

Comment: Lines. 
Concur is the word they use for "Intersects on the same pont"

Comment: If those are lines - how A or A' are defined? Could you have an example of a drawing for AA', BB' and CC'?

Comment: Just a sec, I'm editing the post

Comment: Image is on the link Initial Situation

Comment: If lines are parallel how you get intersections? What is meaning "by thirds"?

Comment: I would really want to know that, because one of my constructions was paralels. 

In groups of three.

Comment: Specifically, if $A_1:=\overleftrightarrow{BC}\cap\overleftrightarrow{B'C'}$, $B_1:=\cdots$, $C_1:=\cdots$, and $A_2:=\overleftrightarrow{BC'}\cap\overleftrightarrow{B'C}$, $B_2:=\cdots$, $C_2:=\cdots$, then these triples are collinear: $\{A_1,B_1,C_1\}$, $\{A_1,B_2,C_2\}$, $\{A_2,B_1,C_2\}$, $\{A_2,B_2,C_1\}$. (Most likely, "point/line at infinity" interpretations are intended, where appropriate. Or else we impose the condition that none of the given lines are parallel.)

Comment: There is text or book where I can find the way to prove that? Is exactly what they are aksing me to do.

Comment: @GeorgeTheSetist: This is actually [Desargues' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem) being applied to various pairs of triangles with vertices among the six given points.